# Как сделать так, чтобы .exe который переделан из формата .py читал текст?

Tags: python

В коде прописана команда мол "Если человек ввёл 'Y', то читается текст из текстового файла"

```
def dtxt():
    file = open("game.txt", "r")
    cont = file.read()
    print("\n", cont)
    file.close()

def ifelse():    
    if inp == 'y':
        dtxt()
    else:
        quit
ifelse()
```

Он читается(пишет после нажатия кнопки). Но как сделать так, чтобы .exe мог читать этот файл без .txt? Допустим я перекину этот exe на другой комп без txt и не будет же ничего работать.
[image]

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Если нет файла, то и читать нечего. Как можно читать то, чего нет?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял проблема в получении пути к файлу? Вот эти функции должны помочь:

```
def module_path():
    if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
        return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    return os.path.dirname(__file__)

def root_dir():
    absolute = module_path() + '\\'
    try:
        relative = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '\\'
    except NameError:
        relative = ''

    return absolute if len(absolute) >= len(relative) else relative



f = open(root_dir() + "my.txt")
```

Функции немного кривые, но работать будут и при запуске с исходников и при запуске с exe